# Difference between preprocessor directives #if and #ifdef

Tags: c-preprocessor

What is the difference (if any) between the two following preprocessor control statements.

```
#if
```

and

```
#ifdef
```

Comment: They are not macros nor control statements. Their name is "preprocessor directives".

Comment: Edited title. Left the "control statements" in text body for "fuzzy" searches.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You can demonstrate the difference by doing:

```
#define FOO 0
#if FOO
  // won't compile this
#endif
#ifdef FOO
  // will compile this
#endif
```

`#if` checks for the *value* of the symbol, while `#ifdef` checks the *existence* of the symbol (regardless of its value).

Comment: +1 for explicitly pointing out that defining something to zero will disable #if, but not #ifdef.

Comment: If FOO defined non-zero than the compiler compiles.Why?

Comment: @fahad: `#if` checks the *value* of the symbol to see whether it is non-zero (true) or zero (false). Then the block is compiled if the result is true.

Answer (score 40):

```
#ifdef FOO
```

is a shortcut for:

```
#if defined(FOO)
```

`#if` can also be used for other tests or for more complex preprocessor conditions.

```
#if defined(FOO) || defined(BAR)
```

Comment: or my favorite #if 0 instead of commenting multiple lines.

Comment: `if (0)` allows the lines to be compiled in Debug mode, so that you can jump in the block when debugging...

Comment: @pascal: that sounds highly compiler/env specific.  C++ doesn't even define a debug mode (though NDEBUG has meaning in the context of assert). ;-P

Comment: @Tony, pascal: I think Pascal is not talking about #if (0) but if (0). The code won't be executed but compiled i.e. instructions are generated. If optimizations are enabled (typically in "release mode") no CPU instructions are generated.

Comment: If I could have accepted your answer too I would have. +1 instead. :-)

Comment: @JustAnotherProgrammer: If `null` is defined, I guess you can write `#if null`. But did you mean `#if NULL` ?