# mkdir Windows vs Linux

Tags: c++, windows, linux, mkdir

I have a problem while porting a Linux tool to Windows. I am using MinGW on a Windows system. I have a class which handles all the in/output and within is this line:

```
mkdir(strPath.c_str(), 0777); // works on Linux but not on Windows and when it is changed to
_mkdir(strPath.c_str()); // it works on Windows but not on Linux
```

Any ideas what I can do, so that it works on both systems?

Comment: you can figure out which system you are on and use the correct one. something like `#ifdef LINUX ... #else ... #endif`

Comment: Conditional compilation?

Comment: *Aside*: You mean to use `0777`, not `777`. They are very different numbers.

Comment: Why does a standard c function, intended to be portable, need a conditional macro if? Isn't the whole point of having standard library to not need to use macro if? Is the standard library obsolete? Why don't we have a shiny new standard library to supercede stdio and iostream and meet common usecases in a portable way?

Comment: @Dmitry:  `mkdir` not a standard C function.  It's a standard Posix function.  The Posix standards inject functions into the C runtime, which technically makes the headers non-standard from the point of view of the C++ standard.  Many unix-hosted compilers and their corresponding libraries choose to comply with Posix, but Microsoft chooses to comply with the C++ standard.  So, for the subset of Posix functions they provide, Microsoft prepends the names with an underscore, making them "reserved for compiler and library implementers" as the C++ standard allows.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
_mkdir(strPath.c_str());
#else 
mkdir(strPath.c_str(), 0777); // notice that 777 is different than 0777
#endif
```

Comment: "_WIN32 - Defined for applications for Win32 and Win64". (ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) Therefore the check for _WIN64 is not necessary here.

Comment: For reference, that's a great thing to know. Short circuit evaluation makes it moot in this case though.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)` to be valid?  There's no such thing as `#ifdef foo || bar` - it's not valid preprocessor syntax as far as I know.

Comment: @jw013 `#ifdef` is valid in both gnu c++ and the visual studio compilers. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Ifdef.html, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t22e924w(v=vs.80).aspx, and http://stackoverflow.com/a/3803108/1355166 for more info.

Comment: @Greg You misunderstood.  `#ifdef constant_name` is valid.  `#ifdef foo || bar` is not.  `#ifdef` doesn't take expressions.  What compiler do you use that accepts such syntax?

Comment: @jw013 I would say it's valid in visual studio, but now that I'm thinking about it, you're probably right. I will edit the answer with this in mind.

Comment: `_mkdir` is included with `direct.h` in Visual Studio, and does not exist in GCC. You may want to add `#ifdef _MSC_VER` `#include <direct.h>` `#endif`

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use conditional compilation to use the version that applies to the OS you are compiling for.

Also, are you really sure you want to set the flags to 777 (as in wide open, please deposit your virus here)?

Comment: Live dangerously!  ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally compile with some preprocessor directives, a pretty complete list of which you can find here: [C/C++ Compiler Predefined Macros](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/)

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
    _mkdir(strPath.c_str());
#elif defined(__linux__)
    mkdir(strPath.c_str(), 0777);
// #else more?
#endif
```

Comment: @EricJ. - `_WIN32` is defined in 64-bit windows as well.