# Getting a define macro from cmd line with CMake not working

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following code in CMakeLists.txt

```
add_definitions("-DVAR=${VAR}")
```

and run the command like so:

```
cmake -DVAR=ON
```

and in my c++ code I have this:

```
#if VAR
//do this
#else
//do this
#endif
```

The problem I am seeing is always the `#else` statement being executed even though `VAR = ON`.

I saw that it is better to use `#if` and not `#ifdef` in this case from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3803108/13663443 and this does not help me either [CMake conditional preprocessor define on code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201064/cmake-conditional-preprocessor-define-on-code)

Can someone help?

Comment: The numerical value of `ON` is probably 0, which means the `#else` arm will be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#if ON` will be false (assuming `ON` isn't defined somewhere, undefined macros evaluate to `0`).

Try `cmake -DVAR=1` or, if you want to keep your current command line, change your cmake file:

```
if (VAR)
  add_definitions("-DVAR=1")
else()
  add_definitions("-DVAR=0")
endif()
```

The else branch isn't strictly necessary as `#if VAR` will evaluate to false if `VAR` is undefined but it's more reliable as you'll get an warning if something else redefines `VAR`.